# Google Adsense in website (Not wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

This question might be stupid as hell to a lot of people, but I've tried to google around and cannot find any tutorial for this.

I'm trying to add Google Adsense into my webpage, but I don't have wordpress and I don't want to use wordpress for this project. So my question is.. Is it possible to add Adsense to non-wordpress webpage? If yes, how?

```
        <div id="adSense1">
           <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
            <!-- MyDogwalk-Web-Auto -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block;"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-7225493999040026"
             data-ad-slot="2295846616"
             data-ad-format="auto"
             data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
        <script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
         </script>
      </div>
```

This is the code so far.

I've tried to upload the webpage via FTP but it's not working. Sorry for the bad formatted question, I'm so confused regarding to this myself.

I’ve been waiting a lot of hours, still no result!

Comment: Adsens is not for wordpress just use exact code you have on your adsens account. Copy paste it to your html page and when it will be online there will be ads  but you need to wait for a while before they appear and little bit longer first time you use the code.

Comment: @jcubic I've the website online at the moment. And I've waited like 2 hours now, still no result. But my "adSense1" container is using width: 100% and height 200px, do I need to enter width and height that matches an "advertisement banner"? 

In my "Ad units" I also use "Automatic size Responsive"

Comment: Try wait longer first time was taking time when I was inserting the ads, wait until tomorrow if you still will not have them you can ask adsens support.

Comment: Do you have error in console? Can you share the link to that page where you have the ads?

Comment: @jcubic I don't have any errors

Comment: Sorry, I can only give you this link https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1208336?hl=en if this don't help you can only contact support, not sure how fast you will get the answer. Adsens is all automatic.